# What is the appsetting.json version of <defaultProxy>?

Tags: web-config, asp.net-core-mvc

What is the .Net Core appsettings.json version of

```
<defaultProxy useDefaultCredentials="true">
    <proxy autoDetect="True" 
           proxyaddress="http://localhost:8888/" 
           usesystemdefault="False" bypassonlocal="False" />
</defaultProxy>
```

?

Answer (score -3):

Using a tool at http://www.utilities-online.info/xmltojson
I got the following. I didn't test this.

```
 {
      "defaultProxy": {
        "-useDefaultCredentials": "true",
        "proxy": {
          "-autoDetect": "True",
          "-proxyaddress": "http://localhost:8888/",
          "-usesystemdefault": "False",
          "-bypassonlocal": "False"
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Did anybody test this?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the OP meant how do you configure a default (outgoing) proxy in modern ASP.NET Core apps, using appSettings.json; not how to translate XML to JSON.